# "Importerror: no module named zope.interface", but I already installed on my Centos 7

Tags: python, centos7, zope.interface

[image]

Why I cant run this code? I already have zope.interface I have try update the path but still doesn't work, I don't know why. See the image above:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from txws import WebSocketFactory
import json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed with pip there's a good chance it broke the installation.

> After installing the zope module using pip, for example: z3c.password, your zope installation breaks.
>
> This is because pip installs the module in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope` and the original module zope.interface is in `/usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/` and has minor relevance when importing.

To fix this I would try symlinking it like so:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope
sudo ln -s /usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/
```

Comment: there is no directory **/usr/share/pyshared/zope/interface/** in my centos but **/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zope/interface/** is it same?
i try but doesnt work

Comment: Yes they're the same, you would cd to wherever/your/path/to/dist-packages/zope is and then sudo ln -s  /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/zope/interface/

Comment: thanks, it works
but i have new problem **importeror: no module named incremental** any suggest?

Comment: Perhaps the same thing has happened with incremental? Can you see it in your `dist-packages/` folder or in `/usr/shared/pyshared/`?

Comment: All run normally after downgrade the twisted version, thanks